# Is there a general event for button onclick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add sound for UI button onClicks but I don't think adding audio.Play() to every button onClicks is logical. Is there anything on EventSystem that runs when any button clicked in unity?

Comment: see this post https://forum.unity.com/threads/4-6-how-to-detect-if-any-gui-element-has-been-clicked-on.263473/

Comment: You can register multiple event handlers to one buttons onClick. And the same handler can be registered to multiple buttons on Click. At best you might be able to find a case where somebody elses code did teh event handling for you.

Comment: @Christopher I guess his point is to avoid making changes to existing code across the entire app

Comment: @zafar: If this was WPF, I am sure we could find a way to regiter that event with the container the buttons are in. Or some template for all buttons. Kinda like you would apply CSS. | But this is Unity, my experience stops at "they really love the Factory Pattern" and "they hide the game loop a bit too well"

Comment: @Christopher Yes I want to avoid making changes on every button also clicking a button is a very common thing. Adding the sound one by one doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

@zafar suggested a thread and I found a solution like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Button>())
                    soundManager.Play("Tap");
}
```

Comment: Probably this is inefficient but adding sound to every sinlge button one by one doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing might be a more efficient way then what you came up with.

```
//subclass the button
class LoudButton : Button {
    //constructor
    public LoudButton() : base () {
        //Have the constructor add the Event.
        //Optionally, hand the specific sound in as a argument and store it in a property
        base.OnClick += /**/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably also go for this. Note however that Unity's built-in `Button` has a custom editor ([`ButtonEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ButtonEditor.html)) so if you are going to add any serialized fields they won't show up in the Inspector until you create your own custom editor for your type like e.g. `[CustomEditor(typeof(LoudButton))]public class LoudButtonEditor : ButtonEditor{ /* additional implementation for your added fields */ }`